# My Query is consuming an inordinate amount of processor time of the server's CPU

Tags: mysql, cpu, processor

The following query is used to show the "news" which has the highest Hits and dated during the last week.

Since the table now has more then 14000 records, the query is consuming an inordinate amount of processor time of the server's CPU

EXPLAIN:
1   SIMPLE  news    ref     state   state   4   const   20619   Using where; Using filesort

INDEXES:

Edit Edit   Drop Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  20635   A   No
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   state   BTREE   No  No  state   3   A   No
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   priority    BTREE   No  No  priority    1   A   No
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   date    BTREE   No  No  date    20635   A   Yes 
hits    20635   A   No
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   cat FULLTEXT    No  No  cat 1       Yes 
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   title   FULLTEXT    No  No  title   1       No
text    1       No

```
$timeago = strtotime("-1 week");

SELECT id, title, sub_title, date, image_url, hits, text, comment
    FROM news
    WHERE state = '2'
    ORDER BY date >= $timeago DESC, hits DESC
    LIMIT 6
```

My question is how can I manage to recode the query in a way that i can avoid mass consuming of CPU?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Updated my answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [explain plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) to see what is happening.  You would at the very least create an index on date or on date and hits

**Update**
Also below would be better I think,

```
SELECT id, title, sub_title, date, image_url, hits, text, comment
FROM news
WHERE state = '2' and date >= $timeago
ORDER BY date DESC, hits DESC
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing is, MySQL is having to go through all 14,000 records and sort them by time in order to complete your request. You need to index the date/time column to make this query more efficient, otherwise it's going to use a lot of resources and you'd have to upgrade the server significantly.